# pyCharm command line arguments are not working

Tags: python, pycharm

I have read many posting on this and tried everything but somehow I can not pass command Line arguments to my python code in pyCharm. I have done the following

A) pls see first pic attached , when I run the code I get this error

```
C:\Automation\myTest\venv\Scripts\python.exe -s C:/Automation/myTest/myTest.py ABC XYZ
======================================================================
ERROR: ABC (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'ABC'

======================================================================
ERROR: XYZ (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'XYZ'
```

The I tried the same as shown in attached pic without -s option

```
C:\Automation\myTest\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Automation/myTest/myTest.py ABC XYZ

======================================================================
ERROR: ABC (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'ABC'

======================================================================
ERROR: XYZ (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'XYZ'
```

code

```
class Ktests(unittest.TestCase):
@classmethod
def setUpClass(self):
    super(Ktests, self).setUpClass()
    self.prepareInitalData(self)

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(self):
    print('Tear Down')
    super(Ktests, self).tearDownClass()


def prepareInitalData(self):

          do stuff

def otherMethod(self):
        do Other stuff

def test(self):
    self.suites()

def suites(self):
     runTest1()
     ....

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

[image]

Comment: You have test modules named `ABC` and `XYZ`?

Comment: You might need to provide the source to `myTest.py`.

Comment: source myTest.py is extremely large , the ABC and XYZ are parameters

Comment: if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what's in `myTest.py`, this is a bit of a guess, but if you're invoking `unittest` or a test runner when the file is run, then the parameters are interpreted as test modules to run. In other words, `unittest` is looking for Python test modules called `ABC` and `XYZ`. And if `ABC.py` and `XYZ.py` don't exist, you'd get exactly the sort of error you're seeing.

If you want to have your own parameters, in addition to `unittest`'s expectations, you can modify your call to `main()` by passing in arguments directly. For example if you want to use the first to arguments (after the program name) for yourself, and pass the rest to `unittest`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arg1, arg2 = sys.argv[1:3]
    unittest.main(argv=sys.argv[3:])
```

This will assign the first to arguments to variables you can use, and then passes any others to `unittest`. So you could make the call in your original question:

```
python myTest.py ABC XYZ
```

Or you can do that, plus run a specific test:

```
python myTest.py ABC XYZ path.to.test.module
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.main

Comment: getting an error --> unittest.main(argv=sys.argv=sys.argv[3:])
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. That line should be `unittest.main(argv=sys.argv[3:])`